# Simplifying a subindex equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, exponentiation, index-notation

Consider the following equation
$$
\frac{e^{\sum_i \alpha_i x_i}}{\sum_i x_i}=\sum_k\frac{e^{\sum_i \alpha_i y_{i, k}}}{\sum_i y_{i, k}}
$$
Is it possible to write $x_i$ as a function of the terms $y_{i,k}$? If not, is there any way of simplifying this relation?

**My approach:** Rewriting, we have
$$
e^{\sum_i \alpha_i x_i-\log\left( \sum_i x_{i}\right)}=\sum_ke^{\sum_i \alpha_i y_{i,k}-\log\left( \sum_i y_{i,k}\right)}
$$
but it still seems quite untraceable to relate $x_i$ and $x_{i,k}$. If, in a simpler example, we had the relation
$$
e^{\sum_i x_i}=\prod_k e^{\sum_i y_{i,k}}
$$
this could be simplified to
$$
e^{\sum_i x_i}=e^{\sum_i \sum_k y_{i,k}}
$$
and thus the relation $x_i=\sum_k y_{i,k}$ is a potential relation (though not necessarily unique). Can we say something similar about the general case? Could Taylor help?

Comment: Please write your thoughts upon this. It might help you to generate more optimal responses :)

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried, but it seems quite untraceable. I also gave a simpler example, for context. Any ideas?